# Portmap.io not working with Huawei router?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, openvpn

Hey I wanted to try port forwarding using Portmap.io OpenVPN connection but It's not working with my Huawei router I tried using mobile data and It works fine with It

Answer (score 0):

Huawei routers also support port forwarding by providing VPN connection. You may need to make some configuration adjustments on the Huawei router to be able to port forward with a VPN connection. In order to perform port forwarding on Huawei router with OpenVPN connection using portmap.io, you need to create a port forwarding service. You can review the steps you need to follow about creating a port forwarding service in detail in Huawei's [documentation](https://support.huawei.com/enterprise/en/doc/EDOC1000097207/54e7ccb3/port-forwarding). You can also check out Huawei's [documentation](https://consumer.huawei.com/en/support/content/en-us15806329/) on port mapping configurations. I hope it will be useful for you.